# Javascript loop an array to find numbers divisible by 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am needing to find the correct way to have javascript loop through an array, find all numbers that are divisible by 3, and push those numbers into a new array.

Here is what I have so far..

```
var array = [],
    threes = [];

function loveTheThrees(array) {
    for (i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    threes = array.push(i % 3);
  }
  return threes;
}
```

So if we pass through an array of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] through the function, it would push out the numbers 3 and 6 into the "threes" array. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: function loveTheThrees(a) { a.filter(function(a, i) {return a % 3 == 0}) }

Comment: You are pushing `i%3` into `array` and then reassigning all of `array` to three. Suggestions are to use more meaningful names rather than `array`, learn about array and assignment operations in js

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this task.

> `filter()` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which `callback` returns a true value or [a value that coerces to `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the `callback` test are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

```js
function loveTheThrees(array) {
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return !(a % 3);
    });
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(loveTheThrees([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Damn you won by quicker fingers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [],
three = [];
 
function loveTheThrees(array) {
    for (i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(array[i] % 3 == 0){
            three.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return three;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].filter(function(a){return a%3===0;}));`

Array.filter() iterates over array and move current object to another array if callback returns true. In this case I have written a callback which returns true if it is divisible by three so only those items will be added to different array

Comment: Array.filter() iterates over array and move current object to another array if callback returns `true`. In this case I have written a callback which returns true if it is divisible by three so only those items will be added to different array

Answer (score 0):

Check if the number is divisible by 3 if so then add it to array. Try this

```
function loveTheThrees(array) {
    for (i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
      if(array[i] % 3 == 0){
        three.push(array[I]);
     }
  }
```

Comment: If anybody can edit this code block it will be helpful. I am on mobile app and no feature to add code block.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`loveTheThrees=(arr)=>arr.filter(el=>Boolean(parseFloat(el)) && isFinite(el) && !Boolean(el%3))`

es6 version + skipping non numbers

loveTheThrees([null,undefined,'haha',100,3,6])

Result: [3,6]

Answer (score 0):

Using Filter like suggested by Nina is defiantly the better way to do this. However Im assuming you are a beginner and may not understand callbacks yet, In this case this function will work:

```
function loveTheThrees(collection){
        var newArray = []
        for (var i =0; i< collection.length;i++){
            if (myArray[i] % 3 === 0){
                newArray.push(collection[i])
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
function loveTheThrees(array1) {
  var threes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] % 3 === 0) {
      threes.push(array1[i]);
    }
  }
  return threes;
}
loveTheThrees(originalArray);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
const arr = [1, 33, 54, 30, 11, 203, 323, 100, 9];

// This single line function allow you to do it:
const isDivisibleBy3 = arr => arr.filter(val => val % 3 == 0);


console.log(isDivisibleBy3(arr));
// The console output is [ 33, 54, 30, 9 ]
```